# can not retrieve a cookie value from echo $_COOKIE['name'] in php

Tags: php, cookies

```
setcookie(name, value, expire, path, domain, secure, httponly);
```

When  I try to `echo $_COOKIE['name']`, it print a blank

Comment: are you using setcookie as mentioned above?

Comment: provide code your using for set cookie

Comment: <?php
$cookie_value = "menuopen";
setcookie("action", $cookie_value, time()+3600, "/", "acvd.com", 1, 1);
?>
I have set like this...

Comment: @Shivinnarayan Then is the name `action` and not `name`! Try to `echo $_COOKIE['action']`

Comment: @Rizier123  yes I had used  $_COOKIE['action'] to  print cookie value :)

Comment: @Rizier123 my problem still there ,

Comment: <?php

    if(!isset($_COOKIE['test'])) {
        $cookie_value = "menuopen";
        setcookie("action", $cookie_value, time()+3600, "/", "acvd.com");
    }

    if(!empty($_COOKIE['action']))
        echo $_COOKIE['action'];


?>

Comment: This code works fine for me! are you sure your domain is acvd.com ? if your on localhost then delete this argument! Also check that your browser has cookies enabled!

Comment: <?php

    if(!isset($_COOKIE['test'])) {
        $cookie_value = "menuopen";
        setcookie("action", $cookie_value, time()+3600, "/", "mysite.com");
    }

    if(!empty($_COOKIE['action']))
        echo $_COOKIE['action'];


?>
It print a blank

Comment: Did you refreshed your page?

Comment: @Rizier123  setcookie("action","menuopen",time()+3400)  this is working for me, when I add next two parameter It would print blank

Comment: Then most likely your domain is false! Are you on localhost?

Comment: I am testig in server , Not in my system and my domain is correct

Comment: If your domain is: `www.acvd.com` then the parameter is: `.acvd.com`!

Comment: Still print a blank :( :(

Comment: @Rizier123  I told you setcookie("action","menuopen",time()+3400) this is working for me, :( :(

Comment: Then i guess your browser has disable cookies! So check that and enable it! This should work fine!

Comment: Nooo, cookie is already enabled

Comment: If you check your site information does it say that a cookie is set?

Comment: NO.  cookie is not set

Comment: If you have a localhost server like: xampp, wampp or so test it on the local server and look if it works! If yes it's to 90% a server problem and i would call your provider!

Comment: when we using localhost, what should we put in domain and path in secookie ????

Comment: Try what you have said it does not work: `setcookie("action","menuopen",time()+3400)` (Because this has to work for SURE!)

Comment: yeah, this is working.... both localhost and remote server

Comment: my problem is when I using additional parametr for setting cookie, it doesnt work
setcookie("action", $cookie_value, time()+3600, "/", ".acvd.com");

Comment: Okay the first test it only with the path argument! Does this works? Also is your domain acvd.com? And if it does not work why do you need it?

Comment: Yeah using only path , its working ...
setcookie($cookiename,$value,$expiry,$path);

Comment: Is your domain `acvd.com` ? If yes the argument is `".acvd.com"`!

Comment: Also did you tried with the empty domain argument like: `""`

Comment: yeah, I put the same ,but when adding this , setcookie doesnt work
when put empty arguemt for domain, its works

Comment: Then use the empty argument! This has the advantage that the setcookie also works for localhost!

Comment: But I wish I could use domain,secure,httponly for extended security :( :(

Comment: @Rizier123  : I understand my problem is, when I put domain name Chrome broswer doesnt set any cookie, but firfox does!

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
<?php

    if(!isset($_COOKIE['action'])) {
        $cookie_value = "menuopen";
        setcookie("action", $cookie_value, time()+3600, "/", ".acvd.com");
    }

    if(!empty($_COOKIE['action']))
        echo $_COOKIE['action'];


?>
```

You have to look that your using the right name of the cookie also that `acvd.com` is your domain! And you can't have a secure connection but httponly!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
            $cookie_value = "menuopen"; 
            if(!empty($cookie_value))
            {
             setcookie("action", $cookie_value, time()+3600, "/", "acvd.com", 1, 1); ?>
           }
```

?>

I hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

first Check the cookie name you have used during setcookie method 
You can also check your cookie value in browser following are the steps:
1 open debugger tool
2 go to resource tab
3 then go to cookies 
4 then go to your domain name

there you will find the cookie name with corresponding value, check for your name is it there and what is the name whether it is name or action.
if name then echo $_COOKIE['name']
if action then echo $_COOKIE['action[image]']